# Getting io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException at Server side when receiving message from Order Management System in Netty

Tags: java, server, out-of-memory, netty

I implemented a basic Server program using Netty. OMS sends group of message strings to the server and the server accepts and displays it to the terminal.I can't receive the message.It is showing the below Exceptions instead.I think the decoded size has exceeded the maximum limit.

If this is correct how to decode any sized string?? That is,is there anyway that dynamically takes the length of the string and receives the exact string from the Buffer?

**My Client Code:**

```
 public class EchoClient {

        private final String host;
        private final int port;

        public EchoClient(String host, int port) {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
        }
    public void start() throws Exception{
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try{
     Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
     b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
             .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
             .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>(){

             @Override
             public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception{
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(204800, 0, 4, 0, 4)) 
            .addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(4))
            .addLast(new EchoClientHandler());
       }
                  });
                ChannelFuture future = b.connect().sync();
               future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
         }

            finally {
                group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
            }
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
            new EchoClient("127.0.0.1", 11235).start();
        }
    }
```

**My ClientHandler :**

```
public class EchoClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>{

@Override
 public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
   System.out.println("Connected");
   int i=0;
   while(i<100){
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("8=FIX.4.29=0007935=A49=TTDS68AO56=RaviEx34=152=20170427-14:05:04.572108=60141=Y98=010=242\n", 
CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

  i++;
  }
}

 @Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
   System.out.println("Client received: " + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause){
     cause.printStackTrace();
     ctx.close();
   }
}
```

**My Server:**

```
public class EchoServer{

 private final int port;
 public EchoServer(int port) {
      this.port = port;
 }

 public void start() throws Exception {
     EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
     try {
           ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
           b.group(group)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
             @Override
              public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception { 
        System.out.println("New client connected: " + ch.localAddress()); 
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(204800, 0, 4, 0, 4))
                .addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(4))
                .addLast(new EchoServerHandler());
       } 
         });


         ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
         f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
     }
     finally {
                group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
            }
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        new EchoServer(11235).start();
        }
}
```

**MyEchoSeverHandler:**

```
public class EchoServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        System.out.println(in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));        
       }

      @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Need some investigation about the configuration of LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder and LengthFieldPrepender. I guess the configuration is not right to encode and decode correctly the lenght on each side

Comment: Even though I am sending a string with 190 bytes its giving me the same Exception. Could you elaborate what you have said?. May be, it can help me.

Comment: Check the javadoc about the decoder and the prepender, both of theses classes accept some parameters to adjust and skip bytes, and both of them need to have parameters which work together (the prepender must add a header that the decoder is able to decode correctly). I think the problem is here, your header is probably wrongly encode and the length during decoding process is wrong. 
You can also add a new LoggingHandler( LogLevel.INFO ) at the begining of your pipeline to see all events on pipeline, specially what is written or read